# Iphone headphones volume very low on certain apps

Tags: ios, audio, headphones, sound-volume

I have the new in ear headphones from apple.

I don't know if it's fault of the headphones, but the volume for certain apps, especially calling, and podcast, is very low! I mean when I'm driving the sound of the engine or the wind is stronger and even if I use the phone external speaker I can hear more.

Some apps, like music apps have a slightly louder volume.

Is this normal? It's the headphone fault, or something related to ios and there's nothing to do about it?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you have your max volume level down in Settings - music - Volume limit, try, may be it helps.

Comment: nope, limit is already removed

Comment: Restore all settings, did you try it? Or maybe it's the speakers in your headphones trouble, did you try another variant? Try to check them in other device and other headphones with your device.